# What 80s tv series or move is this?

Tags: story-identification

All I remember is a man walking out of some od or something like and igloo or something and there is a spot light on him - the entire environment is black except for the spot light on him.  Then to the characters left, maybe 100 meters away in the blackness another spotlight shows another man staring at him.  All the other man does is whistle two notes (like calling to him...)

I thought it was from the 80's TV series V but I couldn't find it.

Comment: Any other information? Was this in the US, UK, other? Over the air, cable?

Comment: Do you remember a science fiction or fantasy element that would make this on topic here?

Comment: This was in Canada.  I really thought this was related to the tV series V.  It is science fiction in that it was a black environment.  I want to say that the main character (the first man I mentioned) somehow got to this place by sneaking onto a ship or some kind of telepathic means.  All I got.  Its super creepy

Comment: The other man that whistles to him I think is somehow letting him know he has been busted.  When the man whistles we only see him in a very wide shot so you can't make out his face or anything.

Comment: One guy whistling to another guy? That's all you remember? If anyone can actually get it, I'll buy a hat and eat it.

Comment: Was there something to do with Tibet, Shangri-La, maybe Paradise Lost?

Comment: `walking out of some od`, what's an 'od'?